# Utilizar sessão de um Browser Selenium em outra navegação

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Tenho um projeto em Selenium que faz o login em um site e devolve em um endpoint os cookies gerados nesse login. 
Outro projeto consome esses cookies e injeta no seu proprio browser para continuar a navegação. Porém, percebi que este precisa da sessionId para realizar algumas operações dentro do site.
Como injetar a session id de um browser em outro?